# Word 2016 brings up Windows Security dialog box to connect to OneDrive

Tags: windows-10, login, onedrive, microsoft-office-2016

I have Microsoft Office 2016 installed on Windows 10. For several months had has worked fine. I have a Microsoft account and regularly save and load files from OneDrive.

Now, however, when I try and access files saved on OneDrive within Word I get a Windows Security dialog box asking for a username and password to d.docs.live.net.

I am not sure what I would have done to cause this behavior. I have tried signing out and back in to Office and to Windows itself. The behavior persists.

Further information:

I can open my OneDrive by going to File > Open in Word, and I have full read/write access without any Windows Security prompt. If I attempt to save a file there, I get the prompt.

Comment: from looking online, it is quite normal for files to connect to a subdomain of `.doc.live.net`. each application(filetype) has its own subdomain, and `d.` appears to be the correct one for Word Documents. As for your login, I'd guess that it has to do with your cookies (most web resources do). Try logging in via a webbrowser and check the "Remember Me" box so that the cookie is created and marked as Persistent. Check your browser and system for addons/utilities that delete cookies. Many of them (like CCleaner) will allow you to exclude certain cookies.

Comment: also, see if this answer does the trick for you. It looks like your login can get corrupted in the credentials manager,and removing it and re-adding may address the problem: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_winother/connecting-to-ddocslivenet-enter-your-credentials/da944c16-ad63-4c4b-905e-1eec417cd5f4

Comment: I tried the credential manager, but it does not do anything differently.